# Vous savez qui on attend? Why "qui" and not "que"?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, pronoms-relatifs, interrogative, pronoms-interrogatifs

I'm learning french with Babbel, and there is one vocabulary item that confuses me. The French sentence is

> Vous savez qui on attend?

On the German side of this card in Babbel it says

> Wisst ihr, wer erwartet wird?

which, in English, would be

> Do you know who is (being) expected?

The french sentence literally translates to

> Do you know whom we expect?

or

> Do you know whom we are waiting for?

My question is: Why do they use *qui* and not *que* in this sentence, as the person in question (the one we expect) is the object. I would have expected something like

> Vous savez que l'on attend?

Then again, I'm still not familiar with this type of sentence in french. Doing some research, it is apparently called an [Interrogative content clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_clause).

Comment: That German translation is somewhat off the mark...  More like: "*Ihr wisst, auf wen wir warten?*". The verb "attendre" can mean either "warten" or "erwarten", depending on context, and in this case, "warten": "*etw von jdm erwarten*" = "*attendre qch de qn*" vs "*auf jdn warten*" = "*attendre qn*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Vous savez qui on attend.

On a ici une phrase complexe. 
*Vous* est le sujet, 
*savez* est le verbe,
*qui on attend* est la proposition subordonnée complétive.

Regardons la proposition subordonnée. Pourquoi emploie-t-on *qui* ici ? *Qui* peut être le sujet ainsi que le complément d'objet. Exemples :

1) Sujet :

Qui a téléphoné ? (On peut également dire Qui est-ce qui a téléphoné ?)

2) Complément d'objet :

On attend qui ? (ou Qui est-ce qu'on attend ? ou Qui attend-on ?)

J'espère que c'est plus clair maintenant.

Comment: Si, *qui* est ici le complément d'objet direct du verbe attendre.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your last question

> Vous savez que l'on attend?

means

> Do you know that we are waiting?

Comment: You are right, I had not thought of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Contrairement à l'anglais (waiting **for**) ou à l'allemand (warten **auf**) le verbe attendre est un verbe transitif (il introduit un complément d'objet (sans préposition)). Il y a donc deux pronoms relatifs possibles selon que l'objet de l'attente est une personne ou "une chose".

Pour une personne, on utilise **qui**

> Savez-vous qui on attend ? Mon frère.

Pour une chose (animal, événement, objet...)

> Savez-vous ce qu'il attend ? La fin de l'orage / le train.

Remarque: même s'il est correct de dire "Vous savez qui on attend?", je préfère l'inversion sujet/verbe ("Savez-vous qui on attend?") qui marque mieux l'interrogation.

Answer (score 0):

The construction used appears to be correct (as it is, with its anomaly) but it is just possible for it to be issued of a more formal construction that **is**, except for register, totally equivalent **and** without the problem highlighted in the question. I'm talking of

> Savez-vous qui est-ce [que l'on/qu'on] attend?

"qui" is the subject of the verb "être". You could also say

> Savez-vous qui est (*ou* sont) cette personne (*ou* ces gens) que l'on attend?.

I could not assert that for a fact but it might be the thing to look into if possible.

When what one is waiting for is not a person there is no anomaly, which might tend to confirm what is advanced as likely above.

> Savez-vous quoi nous attendons qu'il arrive à Noël ?

Nevertheless, here also, we have a colloquial form ; the standard form (equivalent) is the next :

> Savez-vous ce que nous attendons qu'il arrive à Noël ?

"que" has been changed into "quoi".

Comment: Thanks! So **qui** is used when we refer to one or several persons, regardless whether they are subject or object. And when it's not a person, one may use **ce que** or **ce qui**. Example: *Savez-vous ce qui m'amuserait le plus?* where the amusing thing is the subject. Could you also say: *Savez-vous quoi m'amuserait le plus?* in this case?

Comment: @Stefan Hamcke je suis sûr que « Savez-vous quoi m'amuserait le plus? » se dit assez couramment; ce n'est pas la seule forme cependant: peut-être plus courant est : « Vous savez quoi m'amuserais le plus? »; mais un bon registre de langue parlée exige « ce qui »: soit «Vous savez ce qui m'amuserait le plus? » soit « Savez-vous ce qui m'amuserait le plus? ».

Comment: *Savez-vous quoi* isn't a colloquial form. It's just plain wrong.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez Mais est-ce que vous avez l'impression de ne jamais entendre des gens le dire?

Comment: Il m'est peut-être arrivé d'entendre « Tu sais qu'est-ce qu'on attend qu'il arrive ? » ou « Tu sais c'est quoi qu'on attend », mais c'est pas ce que j’appellerais du « colloquial », c'est du langage qui reste très très stigmatisé. « Savez-vous quoi nous attendons » ? personne ne dit jamais ça.

Comment: @Stéphane Gimenez Je suis bien d'accord, c'est à éviter. Je saurai peut-être maintenant pourquoi je l'évite, parce que c'est tout simplement faux.

Comment: Je rejoins Gimenez.  "Savez-vous quoi nous attendons qu'il arrive à Noël ?" est impossible en français.  Vous avez oublié d'amender la réponse dans ce sens.

Comment: @petitrien Je crois bien que cela se dit dans la langue relâchée ; voilà des paroles d'une chanson des Charlots :  Derrière Chez Moi par Les Charlots _ 
Derrière chez moi, savez-vous quoi qu'y a _ Il est évident que cela vient de « Savez-vous quoi il y a ? ».

Answer (score 0):

En effet, je suis tout à fait d'accord avec vous: le "qui" ne pourrait s'agir que d'une personne si je ne me trompe pas, et d'après ce que j'ai comprise de la phrase: "Qui on participe?" c'est: Qui est ce qui est "on" participe?

Comment: *Qui on participe* n'est pas du français.